# Get the value from drop down and display result in same page in Java script

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, calculator

Here is the header. 
It's giving the result in new page, while I want to show result in the same page where the code is running. Help please.

```
function calculate() {
    var width = document.getElementById("width");
    width1 =  width.options[width.selectedIndex].text;  
    var height = document.getElementById("height");
    var height1 =  height.options[height.selectedIndex].text;    
    var calculate = width1 * height1 * 3;
    result.innerHTML = "<div>" + calculate + "</div>";
}
```

body

```
Choose Width
<select id="width" name="height" onchange="calculate()">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
</select>
<br/>
Choose Heiht
<select id="height" name="height" onchange="calculate()">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>      
</select>
```

Comment: what it means in next page

Comment: OP means to say, the result get submitted on the next page but he wishes to update/ display the result on the same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use :

```
Choose Width:

<select id="width" name="height" onchange="calculate()">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>

    <br/>

   Choose Height

<select id="height" name="height" onchange="calculate()">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>      
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

and javascript should be :

```
function calculate()
{
    var width = document.getElementById("width");
    width1 =  width.options[width.selectedIndex].text;  
    var height = document.getElementById("height");
    var height1 =  height.options[height.selectedIndex].text;    
    var calculate = width1*height1*3;
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    result.innerHTML = calculate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have `result` as a div in your HTML code and then you need to do innerHTML or innerText to place your result
Add new tag (in your HTML Code)

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Now in JS update this div element

```
var result = document.getElementById("result");
result.innerText = calculate;
```